# How to run onClose operation after creating Flux.fromIterable?

Tags: java, project-reactor, flux, reactor, autocloseable

Suppose we need to create a `Flux` based on contents of a `Closeable` resource.
For clarity say there is a `BufferedReader` to be converted to `Flux<String>`.

```
BufferedReader reader = createReader("my_resource_path");
Flux<String> flux = Flux.fromIterable(() -> iteratorOfLines(reader));
```

Let us assume that `iteratorOfLines` produces a finite set of items.

I'm looking for a way to close `BufferedReader` when either the `Flux` has consumed all data from it or the remaining data is not needed for some reason (i.e. subscription is aborted).

There's a constructor `reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable(Iterable iterable, Runnable onClose)`, but:

1. seems that it is not reachable (even transitively) from public API of reactor
2. I doubt that it can help, because it does not cover the case when Flux stops before getting the last item in the iterable.

---

What is the proper way of cleaning/closing resources after `Flux.fromIterable` publishes the last item?

Probably, there is a better way than `fromIterable` to do similar things, so all options are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an equivalent to try with resources you can use `using`

```
    Flux.using(
            //Set up resource
            () -> createReader("my_resource_path"),
            //Create flux from resource
            reader -> Flux.fromIterable(iteratorOfLines(reader)),
            //Perform action (cleanup/close) 
            //when resource completes/errors/cancelled
            reader -> {
                try{
                    reader.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    throw Exceptions.propagate(e);
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted - I prefer it to `doFinally()` personally.

Comment: I believe this is much cleaner solution in case of working with closeable resources. Seems to me that `doFinally` belongs to a different layer of abstraction, namely - to the publications life-cycle maintenance.

Comment: @diziaq Yep, I personally prefer this for any resources since it keeps everything neatly packaged in one place in the chain